# How do I use a broadcast receiver in an library?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My app has a library that needs to receive a broadcast from one of the app's activity. I tried using the same in library code but was not able to use it. Need some help regarding how to receive a broadcast from app's activity in library.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is that you **build a wrapper** that extends your library code. There you can add whatever logic you wish.

Also, this would make writing unit tests for the library easier, since you could mock your wrapper.

Goodluck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl)? You can simply use interface to create communication channel between your app and the library and send data. Marshaling custom objects is expensive so extra care must be applied when designing your architecture. This is would be the best solution to your particular problem, in my opinion.